# Html2canvas are not working on Google line chart in angular.js

Tags: angularjs, html2canvas

Please help me. I am trying to convert a line chart to canvas image.

```
$scope.export = function() {
    html2canvas($('#div'), {
        useCORS: true,
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas)
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var svgString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.querySelector('svg'));

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
var img = new Image();
var svg = new Blob([svgString], { type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8" });
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

img.onload = function() {
   ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
   var png = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
   DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(png);
   img.src = url;
}
```